# ASP.NET Web Api with Angular Frontend not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular

I was trying to follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022) on ASP.NET Web Api and Angular. I followed it step by step with the only difference being I used .NET version 7 for the Web Api instead of 6. When I ran the project for the first time I got this inthe output:

```
<e> [webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/weatherforecast 
to https://localhost:5290/ [EPROTO] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

In the guide they addressed this issue by saying

> If you see this issue, most likely the frontend started before the backend. Once you see the backend command prompt up and running, just refresh the Angular App in the browser.

So I made sure the Api was running, then reloaded the browser, but the error stayed. I can't seem to find enybody with the same problem.

launchSettings.json

```
{   
    "profiles": {
        "http": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchUrl": "swagger",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          },
          "dotnetRunMessages": true,
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5290"
        },
        "https": {
          "commandName": "Project",
          "launchUrl": "swagger",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          },
          "dotnetRunMessages": true,
          "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7294;http://localhost:5290"
        },
        "IIS Express": {
          "commandName": "IISExpress",
          "launchBrowser": true,
          "launchUrl": "swagger",
          "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
          }
        }   
    },   
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",   
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
          "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:32492",
          "sslPort": 44306
        }   
    } 
}
```

Proxy.conf.js

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:5290",
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Also I think the guide must be outdated, so if anyone knows of a newer guide, please point me to it.

Comment: @NilsKähler I did not change anything in that file, the two URLs were there by default. But adding the 's' at the end of 'http' did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what helped me:

1. Make sure you have the version of Node.js that Angular supports
2. The ASP.NET Core SSL certificate must be validated. Visual Studio gave me a warning about this after I closed the Angular console

After I solved these problems, ASP.NET Core worked/

I myself only understand this, so it's hard for me to say why it works this way and not otherwise.